# M/D/YYYY h:mm tt to DATETIME SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert string date into a datetime datatype in sql server. This question was asked in a different forum however my situation is a bit different 
These are the possibilities of string date

```
tt= AM or PM

M/D/YYYY h:mm tt
M/DD/YYYY h:mm tt
MM/D/YYYY h:mm tt
MM/DD/YYYY h:mm tt

M/D/YYYY hh:mm tt
M/DD/YYYY hh:mm tt
MM/D/YYYY hh:mm tt
MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm tt
```

This same question was asked in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c0a7f57-123b-4312-b562-57459fef733a/mdyyyy-hmmss-tt-to-datetime?forum=sqlintegrationservices

and solution was given

```
    DECLARE @formats TABLE (notADateTime VARCHAR(30))
INSERT INTO @formats (notADateTime) VALUES 
('1/1/2015 1:01:12 AM'), ('1/01/2015 1:12:12 PM'), ('12/2/2015 1:11:12 AM'), ('08/13/2015 1:22:44 PM'),
('1/1/2015 10:01:11 PM'),('1/01/2015 10:12:12 AM'),('12/2/2015 12:5:12 AM'),('08/13/2015 01:44:55 AM')

SELECT *,
LEFT(RIGHT(notADateTime,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(notADateTime))-1),4) + '-' +
RIGHT('00'+LEFT(notADateTime,CHARINDEX('/',notADateTime)-1),2) + '-' +
RIGHT('00'+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(notADateTime,CHARINDEX('/',notADateTime)+1,2),'/',''),2) + ' ' +
RIGHT('00'+CAST(CASE WHEN RIGHT(notADateTime,2) = 'PM' THEN 12 ELSE 0 END + RIGHT('00'+REPLACE(LEFT(notADateTime,CHARINDEX(':',notADateTime)-1),' ','0'),2) AS VARCHAR),2) + ':' +
RIGHT('00'+REPLACE(SUBSTRING(notADateTime,CHARINDEX(':',notADateTime)+1,2),':',''),2) + ':' +
REVERSE(LEFT(RIGHT(notADateTime,CHARINDEX(':',REVERSE(notADateTime))-1),2))
  FROM @formats
```

However no explanation was given and the difference is that I'm trying to do the same conversion with the seconds in the string. When I run that code i get an error because right function integer isn't correct.
Any assistance/ explanation would be extremely helpful

Comment: Can't cast it as datetime? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=da2d948c1bb1e55c32bae395869d1212

Comment: Also see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: I think I need to look at the data a bit more. @McNets I was able use the cast function on some of the data and it worked. When I convert the entire table data i get an out of range value.

Comment: @HuzaifaMAamir Then you now understand why it is a bad, very bad, idea to store datetime values as strings. That allows garbage into the database that will only be trouble to find, purge, correct, or ignore efficiently.

Comment: You say "the difference is that I'm trying to do the same conversion with the seconds in the string"; but it looks like the answer you've linked to *has* seconds and the title of this question doesn't, so I assume that "with" was a typo and should have been "without".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string manipulation is being done to convert it into a recognised ISO standard format. Without doing that, a mistake could be made by doing CAST/CONVERT in confusing the days and months, since different cultures use different date formats. For example 12/2/2015 could represent December 2nd or 12th February.

The answer provided creates a string in the ISO format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss". The first line after the `SELECT` extracts the year and appends a hyphen, the line after that does the month and hyphen, and so on. I'm assuming you spotted the part in that article where the OP pointed out the mistake in the accepted answer.

I assume you know what each individual function does (if you don't, you can search for the definitions on MSDN - do that now, or what follows won't make sense). However, it will probably help to explain some of the patterns being used in the solution when those functions are being used together.

`CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(notADateTime))` is looking at the string back-to-front and finding the *first* `/` (and since the string is backwards, that is the last `/`). So when used in conjunction with 'RIGHT', `RIGHT(notADateTime,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(notADateTime))-1)` is returning the right hand end of the string after the final `/`.

`RIGHT('00'+*value*,2)` is being used to ensure certain values (like hours, minutes, days and months) have two digits. The 2 means they want the final two characters (which will be digits, since this is a number). Note that '00' only needs to be '0', since any integer always has one digit already.

Once it's in that format wrap that in a CAST to DATETIME2, so it isn't a string any more.

Now you have this understanding you should be able to have a go at solving this yourself. Remember that solution expected seconds, which your strings don't have. Let me know if you need more help by adding a comment.

Comment: No, this definitely helps. I will mark this as the correct answer. Thank you! Appreciate you not giving me the answer, and instead providing a explanation